# AndroidのGoogleMusic内の音楽を選択したい。

Tags: android, android-intent

以前 Android 2.1 くらいに作成した Android アプリケーションで

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(MediaStore.Audio.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.setData(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

と書いた場合に音楽を選択することができ、`startActivityForResult`でコンテンツプロバイダのIDデータなどを取得するアプリケーションを実装したのですが、

Android 5.0 で実行したところ、MP4 ファイル等は少数表示されるのですが以前のように音楽情報が選択できなくなっていました。

おそらく原因は音楽アプリケーションが Google Music に移行した為とは思いますが、どうやったら Google Music でも以前と同じ方法で選択・データベースの情報を取得できるのでしょうか？

ご教授願います。

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/*");
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、自分でもこの方法を試していたのですが、
SDカード内のファイルは検出は可能なのですがGoogelMusicのファイルは表示されないのです。

Comment: 音声からいけないですか？　Nexus5では行けたんだけれど

Comment: 音声タブを開いたらSDカードに直接入れたものは検出が可能なようです。ただ、Google Musicでダウンロードしたファイルにはアクセスできないみたいです。
下記のリンクが参考に実装することになるかも知れないです。
[https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61567]
[http://www.acnenomor.com/470574p2/media-album-artist-playlist-intent]